# Calculating unskinned pos from skinned pos

Tags: c++, math, matrix, unreal-engine4

Hey guys I'm trying to calculate the unskinned pos from skinned pos.

A skinned pos is calculated like this:

```
FMatrix Matrices[3];
float Weights[3];
FVector Pos;
FVector NewPos;
for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   NewPos += Matrices[i].TransformPosition(Pos) * Weights[i];
}
```

How do I calculate Pos, when the Matrices, Weights, and NewPos are know?

I know that for a single transformation it is:

```
 Pos = Matrices[0].InverseTransformPosition(NewPos / Weights[0]);
```

Is it even possible to recalculate Pos, and if it is how should that be done?

Comment: You start using the word "vertices", then switch to using "pos".  Are they the same? You need to use consistent terminology within your question.

Comment: yes, they are the same. I updated the question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can think of this `TransformPosition` call as a matrix times vector multiplication. The weight can be applied to the matrix, too. So you have

```
M1*pos*w1 + M2*pos*w2 + M3*pos*w3 = (w1*M1 + w2*M2 + w3*M3)*pos
```

In other words, you can use the weights to scale the matrices, then add the matrices. The result will be a single matrix which combines your whole operation. Then you can use the inverse transformation from that.

```
FMatrix Combined;
for( int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   Combined += Matrices[i] * Weights[i];
}
Combined *= 1 / Combined.M[3][3];
Pos = Combined.InverseTransformPosition(NewPos);
```

The normalization step where I divide by the bottom right corner element shouldn't be neccessary if the engine were handling homogeneous coordinates correctly, but apparently that's not the case. So one shouldn't use `FVector` if the matrices *might* be representing a non-affine projective transformation (last row not `0 0 0 *`) but use an `FVector4` instead. And if one wants to use `FVector` one has to scale the matrix to make the last row `0 0 0 1` as I do above.

Comment: I don't have unreal installed. What *do* you get instead? Is `NewPos` as expected?

Comment: I accidentally deletd my previous comment, but I updated the question with more information.

Comment: @user3523937: I think I identified the problem; updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Sorry for my confusion, but what is that 'M[3][3]' ?

Comment: @user3523937: the last entry of the last row of the matrix `Combined`. Should have used that name. Might have to be written as `Combined.M[3][3]`, though, I'm not sure.

Comment: After some further testing this still doens't give me exactly what I want. I have updated the question with more information.

Comment: @user3523937: Probably your incoming matrices already have something other than `0 0 0 1` in their last row. In that case, are you sure that the operation they expressed so far was the one you intended?

Comment: Ah yes, I was using the wrong matrices, sorry for that. it's fixed now. Thanks.